# Prove that a function containing $n!$ is decreasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, derivatives, factorial

Taking the derivative of the function $f(n)=n!$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not possible. But is there some alternative way to understand if a function with $n!$ is decreasing (besides the definition of decreasing, i.e. proving that $f(n+1)<f(n)$ directly, which is hard to do in some cases).

For example: suppose that I need to use Leibniz rule of convergence for this series.
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \frac{\mathrm{sin}(n!)}{n^5}$$
Firstly I must prove that $ \frac{\mathrm{sin}(n!)}{n^5}$ is decreasing, but how can I do without taking the derivative?

Comment: The index $n$ is a dummy index.  The series absolutely converges, but is a number and not a function.

Comment: It's not decreasing. Look at $n=11, 12$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$|\sin(x)|\le 1$$ for any $x$.  Thus, with $x=n!$, we have

$$|\sin(n!)|\le 1$$

Comment: This doesn't prove the decreasingness of the sequence (though it can be used to show the absolute convergence of the original series).

Comment: @patrickstevens It is not meant to shown that the sequence is decreasing.  In fact, the sequence isn't monotone.  As you correctly stated, we don't need monotonicity to show that the series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\frac{sin(n!)}{n^5}$ is not decreasing: at $n=11$ and $n=12$, its value goes from $1.255732774 \times 10^{-6}$ to $2.582485596 \times 10^{-6}$.

You should use Dr. MV's hint, though, and a different test for convergence. The $n^5$ is very helpful for you: note in particular that $5 > 2$.

Comment: Is it monotone for $n\ge N$ for some $N$?

Comment: I have no opinion on that question. I just don't know.